Cell Count Calculation in Split View Using FeaturePlot
In single-cell sequencing analysis, the FeaturePlot function allows us to visualize gene expression levels across different cells, and the split.by parameter enables us to create a split view based on a categorical variable, such as cell clusters. My question is, after employing the split view in FeaturePlot with the command FeaturePlot(seurat_object, features = "gene_of_interest", split.by = "cluster_id"), is it possible to perform cell count calculations for each cluster within the split view?


Yes, it's possible - I've added a cluster/bin biplot a function in my Single Cell Browser application - but graphical region selection is not implemented in any of the Seurat functions.
When I do this myself I prefer to use the command line interface rather than the graphical interface. You can use the table function within R to create count bins for multiple features at the same time:
> table(sc.data$cluster, sc.data$sampleTag)

Annotating Seurat plots (like FeaturePlot) with other graphics is possible, but difficult. I've found it easier to fetch the raw data and create a custom display function.
